# Field Wrong Calculations

Tags: excel, pivot, calculated-field

I am using pivot table in excel and I am trying to analyze a dataset and one the things I wanted to add to the pivot table is a calculated field to measure the profit by subducting the Revenue with Budget. I have noticed that the field is not working with its supposed formula it is summing the data from the Raw data ignoring the fomrula completely I tried to figure it out but couldnt find a solution for this please help.

It subducts the cells from the raw data but I want the formulat to subduct them using the Averages that I generated..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFDSQ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EPP2.png)

I tried to change the formula and writing Average before every column but it didnt work. From google sheets there is an option called Custom. Which used the formula instead of the aggregating operations. My problem is that the Averages that I am targeting are not being picked up because I noticed that the formula is working but it is not using the cells I want it is using the cells from the raw data

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve what you want:

Add a new column to your table, called 'Dummy' say, which contains 1 in every row, after which you can use the following Calculated Field:

`='Box Office Revenue ($)' / Dummy - 'Budget ($)' / Dummy`

Add your table to the Data Model and use the following measure within Power Pivot:

`=AVERAGE ( Table1[Box Office Revenue ($)] ) - AVERAGE ( Table1[Budget ($)] )`